# bootstrap-wysihtml5 is not working

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, textarea, wysiwyg

I want to include a WYSIWYG editor in a web page that am designing. I came across [bootstrap-wysihtml5](http://jhollingworth.github.io/bootstrap-wysihtml5/). By the look of it, it is exactly what I want (simple and elegant). I wanted to look at a example but there are not many good examples showing it how to set it up. So far I have done this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Editor</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="bootstrap-wysihtml5.css"/>
    <script src = "bootstrap-wysihtml5.js" type = "text/javascript"></script>
    <script src = "wysihtml5-0.3.0.min.js" type = "text/javascript"></script>
    <script src = "bootstrap.min.js" type = "text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <textarea class="textarea" id="ta1" placeholder="Enter text ..." style="width: 810px; height: 200px">
   </textarea>
   <script>$(".textarea").wysihtml5();</script>
<body>
</html>
```

These are the errors in the chrome console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined             bootstrap-wysihtml5.js:368
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function                        bootstrap.min.js:6
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'wysihtml5'   editor.html:14
```

I don't know what how to solve these errors, where do you think am going wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: *whispers* include jQuery as first script-file

Comment: yep included JQuery! and its working. Previously I had included JQuery  but in the wrong order. Now every thing seems to work fine. Thanks @GNi33

Comment: will you be adding that as an answer @GNi33?? I would be happy to accept.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll need to include jQuery for this to work, as first script-element in your case.

Bootstrap highly depends on jQuery, and probably the "wysihtml5" - plugin too, so jQuery has to be included before those.

You can even see this through the error-log:

The first hint is `fn`:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined
```

`fn` basically is the `prototype` - "wrapper" of jQuery, bootstrap tries to add something to the prototype of jQuery on that line.

Second hint:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'wysihtml5'
```

`$` is bound to a selector-function in Chrome per default, so it returns a usual HTML-Element, not a jQuery-Object in this case. wysihtml5 would most likely bind itself to the jQuery - prototype, so it can be called on jQuery-elements in this way. 
As jQuery is not present, you try to call a function to a normal `Object` that just doesn't exist in this case.

Comment: Note that on the [project's homepage](https://github.com/jhollingworth/bootstrap-wysihtml5/), there is a list of "files to reference" and jQuery is among them.